# Creating a separate Excel process

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that monitors market price of certain securities.

I get this market price from Bloomberg and these values change all the time as long as the market is open.

I have a simple VBA tool that sends me an alert every time the risk is breached.

Unfortunately I run multiple Excel spreadsheets during the day and sometimes when the alert comes up my other macros stop working.

So I'm thinking if its possible for to write something in c# where I can run this excel tool in the background as a totally different process which doesn't interfere with any of my other excel workbooks that are open.

Comment: are you saying all of ExcelSheets which are in different files get frozen?  or they are all part of the same Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to implement your code in `C#`.

Using the above NameSpace you gain Full Access to your Excel object model, and then you can monitor different cells.

Code to read an Excel file using the `C#` are all over the internet.

The good news is the C# application will run in a different thread of your Excel files and does not interfere with them.

Instead of trying to write a tool to run your Excel tool in the background,  the better approach is to write a tool in `C#` to implement it's logic.

Answer (score 0):

Each macro should work independently (unless some of the actions it does include precisely affecting other workbooks). Same thing for C#. When dealing with Excel in C# you have to rely on an `Excel Object/Application` and you can create as many as you wish; each Excel Object is associated with a Workbook/Excel File. You can deal with some of these objects in parallel without any problem (equivalently as should be the case with VBA -> perhaps you have to review the code in your macros).

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) you have a sample code from MSDN showing how to automate Excel with C#.

If you run the small code below these lines, you would see two different Excel files which you might affect in the way you want:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = @"path to first Excel file";
            string path2 = @"path to second Excel file";

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            Worksheet oSheet = (Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL2 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook oWB2 = oXL2.Workbooks.Open(path2, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            Worksheet oSheet2 = (Worksheet)oWB2.ActiveSheet;

            oXL.Visible = true;
            oXL2.Visible = true;

            oXL = null;
            oXL2 = null;
        }
    }
}
```